# Freeware pivot table component for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, components, pivot-table

Is there a pivot table component for Delphi that is opensource or freeware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no freeware pivot component for Delphi. Look up in Torry.net.

The most known pivot component in delphi is ExpressPivotGrid Suite from Develop Express.

Comment: RadarCube (http://www.radar-soft.com/products/radarcube-vcl) are much more powerful

Answer (score 1):

TFX is a free/open source copy of Decision Cube:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fxds