# Crosstab/Cube/Pivot Components for Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, olap, cube, crosstab

I'm looking for a Delphi VCL crosstab/cube/pivotcube/olap grid component for Delphi 2009, 2010, or XE.  I'm willing to sacrifice advanced features to get something open/free (or very cheap if I must) to make it easier to collaborate with any future developers without anyone having to purchase more components than I already use, since this will just be used in one screen.  If there isn't anything appropriate out there, I may try to implement something simple on my own.  I can live with some fairly basic features: drag and drop to configure dimensions, sort by a column, allow totals/min/max for a column, and (optionally) expand/collapse or drill down to sub-categories.  Blazing performance and enterprise scalability are not required, since there should be less than 2000 source rows.

There appear to be several decent options in the commercial space (ExpressPivotCube, FastCube, HierCube), but they are all a few hundred dollars.  This project already uses existing installations of Excel 2007 and SQL Server 2005/2008, so I might consider leveraging those, though I'd prefer a native Delphi component, if possible.  There are also the very old Decision Cube components included in Delphi's Source\xtab directory, but they apparently no longer support unicode compilers (Delphi 2009+), since I got dozens of unicode-related compilation errors while test compiling that source in Delphi XE.  Those components also still link to the long-deprecated BDE!  Has anyone modified Decision Cube to support unicode/pure-TDataSet?  The online tutorials I found were incomplete and silent on the dozens of BDE/unicode compilation errors I see, so I might have to tackle that on my own.

Does anyone have suggestions where to start for a free/cheap basic crosstab/pivot grid component?

Comment: Excel provides a Pivot chart featzre which is quite powerful, does it not meet the basic requirements? With around 50000 rows it is still quite fast too.

Comment: I've used Excel pivot tables and it is powerful and a very reasonable choice, if I can't find a native Delphi solution.  The only downsides I can think of are that it doesn't integrate natively into the application, and does introduce some external app dependencies, but I'm certainly willing to consider it if the preferred options don't pan out.  I haven't searched around to see what the OLE automation code looks like to build Excel pivot tables via code, but I'm sure there are plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

[XLReport from Alfalinasoft](http://www.afalinasoft.com/xl-report/index.html) was a very powerfull library to integrate excel for reporting purpose along with its pivoting capabilities which controlled right from your application. It was said all stuffs would be opensourced, but not known the exact time it would be. Perhaps it'd be worthed to ask the author directly since the promise was made years ago and it is still right there until now.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress Pivot Grid (https://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExPivotGrid/) - it starts from $1000

Much more powerful RadarCube (http://www.radar-soft.com/products/radarcube-vcl) - costs from $200

But in answer to "[Freeware pivot table component for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149370/freeware-pivot-table-component-for-delphi)" had mentioned free/open source copy of Decision Cube, named FXDS: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fxds last update of which was 12 years ago and contain prepared packages for Delphi 6 and Delphi 7.